# React Native Expo - cannot send requests on Android, but can on iPhone

Tags: android, android-emulator, react-native, expo

1. SDK Version: 36
2. Platforms: Android

Hello -

I've been working with expo for some time now, but only using it to build iOS apps.

A current project has a working iOS app that can make requests to my local and production servers. I also have it deployed on iTunes where it works as intended.

I want to have this application on Android as well. The issue I am having is that I cannot make requests to the backend. The same actions working on iOS don't make it to my server on Android.

The error I am receiving after trying a request on the Android emulator is -

```
TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (fetch.umd.js:473)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target-shim.js:818)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:574)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:388)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:501
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:436)
    at MessageQueue.js:111
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:384)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:110)
```

I am hoping I am missing something easy, and any help would be appreciated. I am currently using Android Studio for the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to point my localhost url to `'http://10.0.2.2:8000'`

10.0.2.2 is an alias to the loopback address of the host machine.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding a content-type header to xhr

`xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');`